# Clear React Native TextInput

Tags: javascript, react-native

Working through the Redux AddTodo example in React Native. The first AddTodo example below uses state to store the TextInput value and works fine.

```
class AddTodo extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { todoText: "" }; 
    }
    update(e){
        if(this.state.todoText.trim()) this.props.dispatch(addTodo(this.state.todoText)); 
        this.setState({todoText: "" }); 
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <TextInput 
                value = {this.state.todoText}
                onSubmitEditing = { (e)=> { this.update(e); } }
                onChangeText = { (text) => {this.setState({todoText: text}) } } />
        );
    }
}
```

However following a few of the Redux examples, the following code is much shorter and also works except that the `TextInput` `value` is not cleared after submitting

```
let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {

  return (
      <TextInput 
          onSubmitEditing = { e => { dispatch(addTodo(e.nativeEvent.text)) } } 
      />
  )
}
```

Is there any way I can clear the InputText value from onSubmitEditing?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Add ref to your TextInput, for example:

```
 <TextInput ref={input => { this.textInput = input }} />
```

then call `this.textInput.clear()` to clear your input value

Comment: Nice. Thanks for that.

Comment: I tried on iOS but it does not work. TextInput still keep old value

Comment: @NguyễnAnhTuấn I've tried the newest version of RN (0.55.4) and it still works on IOS.

Comment: @NguyễnAnhTuấn @Kawatare267  @simonthumper Just confirmed. `.clear()` Doesnt work for the new RN (0.55). Have you guys found a work around?

Comment: I confirm that `.clear()` just work on Android, iOS doesn't work. Issue link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/18278, We can use this module as work around the issue: https://github.com/agiletechvn/react-native-text-input-enhance

Comment: @NguyễnAnhTuấn Seems like, react-native-text-input-enhance module only works for english input and it broke for chinese, japanese input etc..(which is the problem on react native side)

Comment: @ThuSama I am not facing even use Chinese or Japanese. Report issue in repo please.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't apply to `multiline` text inputs. No matter what I've tried it didn't work.

Answer (score 37):

For iOS, it will give the default clear text button.

```
<TextInput clearButtonMode="always" />
```

See [the doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#clearbuttonmode)

Comment: for android you need to maintain the state and change accordingly.

Comment: how to maintatin state for android? because i can't see clear button in android

Answer (score 22):

According to changes and recommendations after [React 16.3](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), you will need to retrieve the ref at your constructor using React.createRef:

At constructor function: 
`this.myTextInput = React.createRef();`

At render function:

`<TextInput ref={this.myTextInput} />`

And then you can call

`this.myTextInput.current.clear();`

[1] https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: This question is about react-native and your answer is specific to react.

Comment: This works for me instead of clear..
this.myTextInput.current.value = '';

Comment: I wasted 15 minutes just to find out that it does not work with react-native. please stick to what the question ask.

Comment: this works for me in react-native. just clear didn't, but current.clear is just what i needed

Comment: myTextInput.current.clear(); works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

One simpler approach will be to use the `value` property of `TextInput` and use the component's state value object to set the value of textInput.

```
state = {
   inputTextValue : '',
}
 
submitText = () => {
    //handle the click action

    //add this line at the end of the function after you are done handling with the input text value.
     this.setState({inputTextValue : ''})
}  

<TextInput 
       onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ inputText: text })}
       placeholder="Monday's breakfast"
       value={this.state.inputTextValue}
 />
 <TouchableOpacity 
       onPress={() => this.submitText()}>
       <Text>Submit</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: It should be this.setState({ inputTextValue: '' }) instead of this.state.inputTextValue = '' & this could be the best approach

Comment: missing `this` before `setState({inputTextValue : ''})` on `submitText()`

Answer (score 10):

I am using **Native base** 
and here is how i have made it work

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.searchInput = React.createRef();
}

<Input
    placeholder="Search"
    ref={this.searchInput}
/>
```

then whenever i want to clear i use

```
    this.searchInput.current._root.clear();
```

reference https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18843

Comment: found this error:  TypeError: _react3.default.createRef is not a function. (In '_react3.default.createRef()', '_react3.default.createRef' is undefined)

Comment: in react 16 > there is no need to add createRef in constructor

Answer (score 7):

Because you're using a functional component you can use Hooks as follows.  If you have conditional renders your code check that todoInput is defined  in the function passed to useEffect.  I assumed your state variable is called todoText in the dependency list.

```
import {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';


let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
    const todoInput = useRef();
    useEffect(()=>todoInput.current.clear(),[todoText]);

      return (
          <TextInput 
              ref={todoInput}
              onSubmitEditing = { e => { dispatch(addTodo(e.nativeEvent.text)) } } 
          />
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

this works for me

```
  ref={element => {  
          //Clear text after Input
                this.attendee = element
              }}
              onSubmitEditing={this.handleAddPress}
```

**and** 
`this.attendee.setNativeProps({ text: '' })` //Clear text after Input

Answer (score 3):

React-Native Using Input component from native-base.
This worked for me:

```
<Input ref={input => {this.textInput = input;}}
```

and then:

```
this.textInput._root.clear();
```

Note: Did not have to use React.createRef() to initialise.

Answer (score 2):

Following code sample:

```
<TextInput 
    onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text)} 
    ref={component => this._textInput = component}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
       this.clearText()
     }}
/>

clearText(){
  this._textInput.setNativeProps({ text: ' ' });

  setTimeout(() => {
    this._textInput.setNativeProps({ text: '' });
   },3);
}
```

Comment: I ended up figuring this one out too. It's the only one that works for me. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me..

Init myTextInput at the constructor:

```
this.myTextInput = React.createRef();
```

Add the reference at render function:

```
<Input ref={this.myTextInput} />
```

And then you can call

```
this.myTextInput.current.value='';
```

Answer (score 2):

On my functional Component , I call another function along with submitHandler , that function will take care to clear text

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');
 const anotherFunc = (val) =>{
        setText('');
    }


    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput 
            value ={text}
            onChangeText ={changeHander}
            placeholder = 'Add '
           />
            <Button 
            title = "Add Something "
            onPress = {()=>  {submitHandler(text) , anotherFunc(text)}}
            />

        </View>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @André Abboud by your help i was able to clear my TextInput field but according to my custom TextInput, i made a slight change in implementantion.

Please review the code and approach used for implementation. As far as i know now my requirement of clearing the TextInput as i needed is fullfilled and if required for any changes please notify in comment.

And what i did to make it work is:

**In setupSender.js**

```js
  ...
  this.state = {
    clearInput: false,
    ...
  }

  ...           
  setupSenderSubmit = () => {
      ...
      this.setState({                             
        clearInput: !this.state.clearInput,
      })
      ...
  }
  ...
      <CustomTextInput
        labelText="First Name" 
        onChangeText={(firstName) => this.setState({ firstName })}
        clearInput={this.state.clearInput}
        value={this.state.firstName}
        returnKeyType={ 'next' }
        autoFocus={true}
        onSubmitEditing={() =>  this.input2.current.focus()}
      ></CustomTextInput>
  ...
```

**And in CustomTextInput.js**

```js
  this.state={
    clearInput: this.props.clearInput, 
  }

  ...

  static getDerivedStateFromProps = (props, state) => { 
    if (props.clearInput !== '' || props.clearInput !== undefined) {
      return {
        clearInput: props.clearInput
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  ...

    <TextInput 
      label={this.props.label} 
      value={!this.state.clearInput ? this.state.text : null}
      onChangeText={(text) => {
          this.setState({text});
          this.props.onChangeText(text)
        }
      }
    </TextInput>

  ...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, check your answer as it has been post as code.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a recently answer, I'm using RN CLI 0.70.6 and React 18.1.0. I'm not using EXPO

```
const input = useRef(null)

<TextInput
 ref={input}
 onSubmitEditing={e => {
   //do something here e.g. console.log(e.nativeEvent.text)
   input.current.clear();
  }
 />
```

The trigger is gonna be when you press the "Enter" it's gonna redirect you or do whatever you specified and also clear the current input.

Answer (score 0):

I make this code for clearing TextInput in React Native `OnSubmitEditing` 
you can check my snack: 
https://snack.expo.io/@andreh111/clear-textinput-onsubmitediting

Here is the code:

> ```
> state = {
>     searchInput:'',
>     clearInput:false
> }
> render(){
>   return(
>
>
>
>   <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
>     <TextInput 
>             style={{
>               borderColor:'black',
>               borderWidth:1,
>               width:200,
>               height:50
>             }}
>               onChangeText={(searchInput)=>this.setState({
>                 searchInput
>               })}
>               value={!this.state.clearInput ? this.state.searchInput : null}
>               onSubmitEditing={()=>{
>                 this.setState({
>                   clearInput:!this.state.clearInput,
>
>                 })
>
>               }}
>      />
> </View>
> )
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TextInput
        ref={input => { this.name = input }}
   />

         this.name.clear();
         this.email.clear();
         this.password.clear();
         this.confirmPassword.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      this.state = {
           commentMsg: '',
      }

after submittion 
     if (response.success)
     {
            this.commentMsg.clear();        //TODO me
     }


  <TextInput
     style={styles.textInput}
     multiline={true}
     ref={input => {
     this.commentMsg = input
       }}
     onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({commentMsg: text})}
     placeholder ='Comment'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Work to me...

```
<TextInput
    ref={ref => {
                this.textInput = ref;
              }}
    ...
/>
```

after call function

```
clearMsg(){

    this.textInput.state.value = ''
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't assign directly to state like this.  
`this.textInput.state.value = ''`  
use setState instead   
`this.textInput.setState({value: ''})`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set the value of the `<TextInput/>` the same of the state and after use the data, set the state back to an empty string:

```
//state
const [state, setState] = useState({
  name: '',
  lastname: ''
})

//functions
const newUser = () => {
// Do your magic and after
  setState({
    name: '',
    lastname: ''
  })
}

const handleOnChange = () => {
  setState({
    // change your state
  })
}

//render
<TextInput
  value={state.name}
  placeholder='Name'
  onChangeText={/* execute your handleOnChange() */}
/>

<TextInput
  value={state.lastname}
  placeholder='Lastname'
  onChangeText={/* execute your handleOnChange() */}
/>

<Button title='Saved' onPress={() => newUser()} />
```

Hope to be usefull!

Answer (score -1):

for RN > 0.6

```
const [msg, setMsg] = useState()
```

use value inside TextInput

```
<TextInput 
    onChangeText={(txt) => setMsg(txt)}}
    value={msg}
/>
```

then set state in your button press function like this

```
const pressButton = () => {
    setMsg('')
}
```