# how can I clear Native-base Input text?

Tags: react-native, native-base, react-native-textinput

I try this

```
  <Input placeholder="search...."
         ref={(ref) => { this.SearchInput = ref; }}
         />
  <Button transparent onPress={this.clear}>
      <Ionicons name="ios-close" />
  </Button>
```

and function:

```
  clear = () => {
    this.SearchInput.clear();
  }
```

I get this error:

> this.SearchInput.clear() is not a function

Comment: check this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/a/51988514/6147182

Comment: It works for TextInput but not fot Input native-base

Comment: you aren't use State or Redux or any state manager for control your text input?

Answer (score 5):

This is the running code, change `ref` to `getRef` and use `this.SearchInput._root.clear();` instead of `this.SearchInput.clear();`

```
  clear = () => {
    this.SearchInput._root.clear();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Input placeholder="search...."
              getRef={(ref) => this.SearchInput = ref}
            />
          </Item>
          <Button onPress={this.clear}>
            <Ionicons name="ios-close" />
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

Comment: what is the difference with ref and getRef,

Comment: For me it only worked when I used. "ref" in place of "getRef" in this example

Answer (score 3):

I use value and state to achieve this functionality

here is the example:

```
<Input
  value={ this.state.value }
  onChangeText={ this.onTextChange }
/>
<Button onPress={this.clear}>
  <Ionicons name="ios-close" />
</Button>
```

declare default `value`'s value on `constructor`

```
this.state = {
  value: ''
}
```

listen to onTextChange as follows, this make sure that the value on Input stay the same as we inserting, not blank forever:

```
onTextChange = (value) => {
  this.setState({ value })
}
```

finally, on `clear` function

```
clear = () => {
  this.setState({ value: '' })
}
```

just set back `value` to empty

Comment: Glad I can help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

i totally agree with Muhammad Hanzala as it worked for me on this but there is a little exception which is really important which i had to do to make it work be sure to add the reference of the text input to your constructor like this:

```
constructor()
  {
    ...
   this.SearchInput = React.createRef();
  }
```

A full example will look like this in your input element...

```
<InputgetRef={(ref) => this.SearchInput = ref}/>
```

in your constructor :

```
constructor()
  {
    ...
   this.SearchInput = React.createRef();
  }
```

and finally you can call:

```
this.SearchInput._root.clear();
```

and dont forget to clear your state..