# How to clear the TextInput on React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

it is the state:
`const[value, setValue]= useState();`

it is the code:

```
    <View style={styles.messaginginputContainer}>
        <TextInput
        multiline
            style={styles.messaginginput}
            onChangeText={txt => setNote(txt)}
            value={value}
        />
        <Pressable
                onPress={()=>{
            clearValue('');
        }}
        >
            <View>
                <Text style={{ color: "#f2f0f1", fontSize: 20 }}>ok</Text>
            </View>
        </Pressable>
        
    </View>
```

i dont know how to do this functional

Ok, i can search a little bit more, but i want to enable the vote on my account

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear React Native TextInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249807/clear-react-native-textinput)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45250198/13490165

create a button, then use

```
<TextInput ref={input => { textInput = input }} />
```

and clear like this:

```
textInput.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to clear any text input is by clearing the state like this :

```js
import { TouchableOpacity , TextInput } from 'react-native';

const [ inputValue , setInputValue ] = useState<string>("")

const clearInputValue = (): void => setInputValue("")

return (
    <>
       <TextInput value={inputValue} onChangeText={value => setInputValue(value)} />
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={clearInputValue}>Clear Input value</TouchableOpacity>
    </>
)
```